# Is Sl(2,C) an ideal of gl(2,C)

Tags: lie-algebras

I believe that it is but how can one show this? This is for study so any help would be great and appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you multiply an element of SL(2, C) with, say, a matrix of determinant 2?

Comment: @JustinBarhite I think you are confusing the linear groups $SL(n)$ and $GL(n)$ endowed with usual product, and the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ ($n\times n$ matrices with trace $0$) and $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ ($n\times n$ matrices) endowed with bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derived Algebra of Sl(n,C)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430917/derived-algebra-of-sln-c)

Comment: So we have $[\mathfrak{gl}_n(K),\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)]=\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$, which is the derived ideal, hence an ideal,  see the duplicate.

Comment: Yes I have no idea how I did not think of that..... thank you though @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every Lie algebra $L$ is the commutator subalgebra $[L,L]$ an ideal.
Since it is well-known that
$$
[\mathfrak{gl}_n(K),\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)]=\mathfrak{sl}_n(K),
$$
the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $[A,B]\in\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb F)$ not only when $B\in\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb F)$ and $A\in\mathfrak{gl}(n, \Bbb F)$ (which would be your goal), but also for all $A,B\in\mathfrak{gl}(n, \Bbb F)$. This is due to the identity $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$.